# I am trying to write an SqL query in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume like we have multiple columns in a row

We need to select one specific column and a specific row 
And we need to order by Date Desc

How can we implement this query

```
Select column, * from table  where column like’%abc’
```

And it should order by date desc

And in that column it should be specific row only ‘abc ‘

Select column,* from table where column like ‘%abc’ order by date desc

Comment: If you want one column from one row ... whats the point in ordering the ONE row yo will get returned?

Comment: Is it mySQL r sql-server it cant be both

Comment: Well the syntax to do an `order by date desc` is very complex. It is `ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: You do need to watch out for the Non-Ascii single quotes though `’`. Use `'` instead

Comment: If your'e using SSMS you can't be using MySQL. SSMS is SQL Server Management Studio; it doesn't work with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This query gets the specific column if it has value 'abc' in it.

```
Select yourspecificcolumn from yourtable where yourspecificcolumn like '%abc%' order by  date desc
```